# indexOf is always -1 using regex

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to match some text in a string.

The problem is it is always -1 even if I have a match.

```
holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());

Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");

int start = post.getPublisher().indexOf(tagMatcher.toString());
int end = start + tagMatcher.toString().length();
```

any ideas why start is always -1?

Comment: It returns -1 when there is no match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using it wrong. `String.indexOf()` doesn't use regexps, it just looks for substring (`"[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b"` in your case).

Code should be something like this:

```
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");

Matcher m = tagMatcher.matcher(post.getPublisher());
if (m.find()) {
    // matches
    int start = m.start();
    int end = m.end();
}
```

`find()` can be called several times to find all of the occurences of pattern. Look in the [Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) docs for details.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning -1 because you're looking for the index of the regex pattern itself as a string instead of looking for a match. You need to use the [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object to find an instance of a match.